# Retrieve password from a html-form

Tags: php, html, get

I have a html-form which looks like this:

```
<form action="lib/AdminPage.php" method="post" id="adminLogin">
Admin-Login: <input type="password" name="pw" value="" class="pw">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

AdminPage.php contains the following lines:

```
      <?php


    echo($_GET['pw']);
    echo($_GET['adminLogin']);
    echo($_GET['Login']);
    echo($_GET['id']);
    echo($_GET['value']);
    echo($_GET['name']);

    echo($pw);

    echo($_GET["pw"]);
    echo($_GET["adminLogin"]);
    echo($_GET["Login"]);
    echo($_GET["id"]);
    echo($_GET["value"]);
    echo($_GET["name"]);

?>
```

None of the echoes works, it's always an "`Undefined index`" or "`Undefined variable`" with `echo($pw)`

How can I retrieve the entered string from the from?

Regards

Comment: Your form submission method is POST rather than GET, so why do you expect $_GET to provide the values rather than $_POST?

Comment: $_GET is for variable passed like AdminPage.php?pw=text&adminLogin=true ... $_POST is what you are looking for... indeed $_REQUEST is for both

Answer (score 6):

Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, because you have `method="post"` in your form.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the form using `POST` but looking for `GET` variables. Replace `$_GET` with `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is this:

```
echo $_POST['pw'];
```

Your HTML form has method="post" in it so you get all information from inputs via $_POST instead of $_GET.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `method="post"` in your form `<form action="lib/AdminPage.php" method="post" id="adminLogin">`, variables are accessed as `_POST` variables. So, you should do

```
echo $_POST['pw'];
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `$_POST` array, not `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

Your form uses the `POST` HTTP method, hence this should work.

```
echo($_POST['pw']);
echo($_POST['adminLogin']);
echo($_POST['Login']);
echo($_POST['id']);
echo($_POST['value']);
echo($_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the values. But, you are trying to get those through `$_GET.`

Try changing everywhere `$_GET` by `$_POST`

Change like this  :

```
echo($_POST['pw']);
echo($_POST['adminLogin']);
echo($_POST['Login']);
echo($_POST['id']);
echo($_POST['value']);
echo($_POST['name']);
```